# Can a client server host multiple private ssh key for same profile?

Tags: ssh, authentication, public-key-encryption, private-key

I have a client who is using Tectia Client to connect to our UAT. They created a ssh pair and imported the private key to the profile they are using to connect,and passed us the public key.

Now we want them to connect to our Production Server with the same profile name (requirement-cant change). Can they generate another pair of ssh key and use the newly created ssh key to connect, while keeping the old one they used to connect to UAT?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

For Passwordless authentication we have to generate key and then should be export, If we are generating new key every time, it has to be exported from client side,

example (Linux based ubuntu12.04)
following command is responsible for key generation

> vishwa@vishwa-VirtualBox:~$ ssh-keygen

The key needed to export from client to server client->server will be password less

> vishwa@vishwa-VirtualBox:~$ ssh-copyid user@server-ip

so for every new generation of key we need to export ssh-key from client to server for password less authentication of ssh and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can, you can have as many private/public key pairs as you want. For easier management you can use the `-f filename` option of `ssh-keygen` to give them meaningful names and/or edit the last part of the public key file (the comment part).